# pytest: fixture as argument of a parametizable fixture

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, fixtures

I have a parametrizable fixture that works well. The following function is a dummy one that has the same behavior.

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def parametrizable_fixture(parameters):
    return parameters
```

This works well with most tests as follows:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("parameters", [["param 1", "param 2"]])
def test_dummy(parametrizable_fixture):
    assert parametrizable_fixture == ["param 1", "param 2"]
```

However if I want to put another fixture (as defined bellow) as a parameter for the first fixture, the test fails:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def param2fixture():
    return "param 2"


@pytest.mark.parametrize("parameters", [["param 1", pytest.lazy_fixture("param2fixture")]])
def test_dummy_2(parametrizable_fixture):
    assert parametrizable_fixture == ["param 1", "param 2"]
```

The lazy fixture is not replaced by the value that it should have i.e. I get this error message:

```sh
E      assert ['param 1', <LazyFixture "param2fixture">] == ["param 1", "param 2"]
```

Edit:
These examples use on fixture as parameter within a length two list. This is just to simplify the problem. There are no constraints on the number or the positions of such lazy fixtures taken as parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to replace a part of an argument (`parameters`) by a lazy fixture, but that works only for whole arguments.

The easiest way to fix your example is to use 2 arguments:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("arg1,arg2",
                         [["param 1", lazy_fixture("param2fixture")]])
def test_dummy_2(arg1, arg2):
    assert (arg1, arg2) == ("param 1", "param 2")
```

As mentioned in the comments, this does not resolve the case for the original question, because the number of elements in the tuple is not fixed. There is a [related issue](https://github.com/TvoroG/pytest-lazy-fixture/issues/24) in pytest-lazy-fixture, and [a pull request](https://github.com/TvoroG/pytest-lazy-fixture/pull/40) that aims to fix that - if you feel adventurous, you can apply the PR to a fork and try it out. As mentioned in the PR, this does slow down the plugin quite a bit, but if that is not an issue, it may be a solution.

Comment: This would work fine in this toy example. However, what I am trying to test can takes a list with multiple values with no guaranty that on the position or number of the lazy fixtures it can take.

Comment: Ok, in this case this won't help you - I'll remove the answer.

Comment: I think, you should leave it other users happen to face a similar issue.

Comment: I added a comment about a related issue and PR in pytest-lazy-fixture.

Comment: Between the solution you have proposed, copy-pasting fixture functions or patching the pluging locally, your solution seems the best for me!